# Three.js - Simple custom texture box looks different on the sides than on the up / down faces. Why it happens and how to match them

Tags: javascript, three.js

In three.js when using a single texture for a box the side faces look different than the top and bottom faces.

Why does this happen? and how can I make the textures of the 6 faces look similar?

The following is the part of the code related to texture

```
var corkTexture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'img/cork-256.png' );
corkTexture.wrapS = corkTexture.wrapT = THREE.MirroredRepeatWrapping;
corkTexture.repeat.set( 10, 10 );
corkTexture.offset.set(0.5, 0.5);
var corkMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: corkTexture } );
```

In this url you can see the complete code and the result

http://heyplay.org/animation/index.html

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using a default `BoxGeometry`, your texture will be transformed to fit across the whole surface. This means that for a square texture, a square surface will look correct, but a short surface will have a squished texture, and a tall surface will have a stretched texture.

Consider you have a box that is `10w`×`10h`×`10d`. If you apply a square texture to the box, all sides will look the same. But if your box is `10w`×`2h`×`10d`, then the top and bottom will look correct, but the short sides will have a squished texture, like the problem you're seeing.

You can get the sides of a short box to look similar (and it helps that you have a repeating texture) by adjusting the UV values for either the top or bottom vertices of all four side faces.

Take a look at [Geometry.faceVertexUvs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Geometry.faceVertexUvs). This is where the UV information is stored. Identify which vertices are the ones you want to update, and then change the values of the associated UVs. (Deciding what values to use is beyond the scope of this question, but I recommend doing so based on the aspect ratio of the face vs. the texture.)